# Python2 convert file datatype to binary without saving to directory

Tags: python

I have a file data type. I need to convert it to binary. Is there a way to do it? What im finding out is using

```
open(file_path, 'rb')
```

But using that means I need to save the file first to a directory and its a problem with efficiency. I get the file from HTML form

Comment: you mean you want the contents of the file in binary format?

Comment: yes sir. Since I need to upload it to alicloud OSS and by the documentation it shows that The file objects must be opened in the binary mode

Comment: you already have a file object or you have the file contents?

Comment: file contents only. This is my code

   ```fileobj = file_upload.file```

Comment: What is ur file content class exactly?

Comment: What do you mean sir? Content-Type? image/jpg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using

```
bucket.put_object_from_file('file_upload', fileobj)
```

I use:

```
bucket.put_object('file_upload', fileobj)
```

to upload using network streams